# changing dates for a visitor visa to Australia

Tags: visas, australia

I'm from Argentina and I'm living in New Zealand for a year. I have a visitor visa for Australia. I'm going for 3 days on m way home. But it expires in August and I'm going there at the end of November.Can I change the dates of my visitor do I need to do a new one?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to apply for a new visa https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/visa-about-to-expire